# WPF matrix display issues

Tags: wpf, matrix

I want to make a schedule application where i need a column with all the employee names, the first row should be the current week dates (7 columns for each day) and the rest should be with the working hours  + last 2 columns for total hours.
I have a matrix of bits 27x10
I need to represent this matrix in a WPF (GUI).
The idea is that the user will be able to change the content of specific cell by clicking the relevant button, that represent the specific cell in the matrix , add data to it and save it to a sql database.

I have considered using GRID for this, but due to GUI (Design) issue, it is not possible to use it.

```
 public void DrawButtons()
    {
        int dateCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
        {
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                dateCounter++;
                if (Matrix[i, j] == 3)
                {
                    Button cellButtons = new Button
                    {
                        Height = 20,
                        Width = 50,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue),
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        IsEnabled = true,
                        Content = "Q",
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,

                    };
                    cellButtons.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                    cellButtons.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                    myGrid.Children.Add(cellButtons);

                }
                else if (Matrix[i, j] == 2)
                {

                    Button columnHeaderButton = new Button
                    {

                        Height = 20,
                        Width = 50,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure),
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        IsEnabled = true,
                        Content = "X",
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,

                    };
                    // Need to add weeks
                    columnHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                    columnHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                    myGrid.Children.Add(columnHeaderButton);
                //    ColumnHeaderButtons.Add(columnHeaderButton);



                }

                else if (Matrix[i, j] == 6)
                {

                    Button rowHeaderButton = new Button
                    {

                        Height = 20,
                        Width = 50,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure),
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        IsEnabled = true,
                        Content = "X",
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,

                    };
                    //Add shift
                    rowHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                    rowHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                    myGrid.Children.Add(rowHeaderButton);

                }

                else if (Matrix[i, j] == 1)
                {

                    Button columnHeaderButton = new Button
                    {

                        Height = 20,
                        Width = 50,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure),
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        IsEnabled = true,
                        Content = "Name",
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,

                    };

                    columnHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                    columnHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                    myGrid.Children.Add(columnHeaderButton);


                }
                else if (Matrix[i, j] == 9)
                {

                    Button columnHeaderButton = new Button
                    {

                        Height = 20,
                        Width = 50,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure),
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        IsEnabled = true,
                        Content = "M",
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,

                    };
                  columnHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                  columnHeaderButton.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                  myGrid.Children.Add(columnHeaderButton);
                }
    public int[,] Matrix =
    { 
        {4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8},
        {5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},
        {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9,10},


    };
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Delete all that horrible code and use proper DataBinding. WPF is not winforms.